# How to add FXML with controller to each cell in GridPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following classes and fxmls:

- a tab (TabPane) which contains GridPane.
- MainWindow.fxml which contains the tabs (one of the tabs has the GridPane)
- GAdata.fxml (with GDdataController.java controller class)

I want to have grid with 2 rows and 2 cols

I want to add GAdata.fxml to each cell in the GridPane

How can I add the  GAdata.fxml to each cell ? 
(moreover each each cell will have it's own controller (GDdataController.java ) ?

Comment: Are you sure you need every cell to have a controller? I'd suggest you to use a single controller with different handles for each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the main `.fxml` file, then you can use the

`<fx:include source="">`

wherever you want to add the data from the other `.fxml` file.
For exaple this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
    <GridPane fx:id="pane">
        <fx:include source="Child.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
        <fx:include source="Child.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
        <fx:include source="Child.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
        <fx:include source="Child.fxml" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
    </GridPane>
</AnchorPane>
```